# convert wf4 xamlized <Assign> into c#

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation-4

I’m unable to re-write the distilled piece of XAML below in C#.

```
<Activity 
  xmlns:swm="clr-namespace:System.Web.Mvc;assembly=System.Web.Mvc" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property 
      Name="ViewData" 
      Type="InArgument(swm:ViewDataDictionary)" />
  </x:Members>
  <Assign>
    <Assign.To>
      <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Object">[ViewData("Foo")]</OutArgument>
    </Assign.To>
    <Assign.Value>
      <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Object">["funky foo string"]</InArgument>
    </Assign.Value>
  </Assign>
</Activity>
```

Can anybody shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  dic.Add("foo", "before");
  var activity = new Assign {
    To = new OutArgument<object>(_ => dic["foo"]),
    Value = new InArgument<object>( _ => (object)"after")
  };

  WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity);
```

You have to use the In/Out argument overloads that accept an expression.  Also, I had to explicitly cast the "after" to object, otherwise workflow validation complained about the types not matching up.